# WooCommerce plus and minus buttons

Tags: wordpress, button, woocommerce

I am a Web Developer and I want to make my own webshop with WooCommerce.
But I have a problem,
The plus and minus buttons on the product page are not showing, do anyone know how to get these buttons (maybe to add some code somewhere)?

Answer (score 6):

You need to override the 'quantity-input' from woocommerce in your child theme. This is located in plugins -> woocommerce -> templates -> global -> quantity-input
Copy the contents from this file.In your theme folder create a 'woocommerce' directory.  Create another folder named 'global' in this directory. Paste the contents over here.

Locate the code

```
<input type="number" step="<?php echo esc_attr( $step ); ?>" <?php if ( is_numeric( $min_value ) ) : ?>min="<?php echo esc_attr( $min_value ); ?>"<?php endif; ?> <?php if ( is_numeric( $max_value ) ) : ?>max="<?php echo esc_attr( $max_value ); ?>"<?php endif; ?> name="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_name ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_value ); ?>" title="<?php _ex( 'Qty', 'Product quantity input tooltip', 'woocommerce' ) ?>" class="input-text qty text" size="4" />
```

Above this add this piece of code above it

```
<input class="minus" type="button" value="-">
```

and this piece below it

```
<input class="plus" type="button" value="+">
```

Your overall code would look like this:

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly
?>
<div class="quantity">
<input class="minus" type="button" value="-">
<input type="number" step="<?php echo esc_attr( $step ); ?>" <?php if ( is_numeric( $min_value ) ) : ?>min="<?php echo esc_attr( $min_value ); ?>"<?php endif; ?> <?php if ( is_numeric( $max_value ) ) : ?>max="<?php echo esc_attr( $max_value ); ?>"<?php endif; ?> name="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_name ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_value ); ?>" title="<?php _ex( 'Qty', 'Product quantity input tooltip', 'woocommerce' ) ?>" class="input-text qty text" size="4" />
<input class="plus" type="button" value="+">
</div>
```

Comment: It's worth adding that *any* file found in the WC template folder can be customised/overridden in the same manner by copying it to your theme folder and altering as necessary.

Comment: Thank you a lot, for te answer, but I still have a problem. When I click on the plus or minus button, nothing is happening to the number input.

Comment: @jorenwouters, I know this post is old but I am also getting the same issue. Have you found the solution on this? I think we have to add the script

Comment: I solved it in some way, but don't know how anymore...

Answer (score 4):

@RollYourOwnEd Updated javascript that can prevent quantity goes in minus value :

```
$('.plus').on('click',function(e){

var val = parseInt($(this).prev('input').val());

$(this).prev('input').val( val+1 );


});
$('.minus').on('click',function(e){

var val = parseInt($(this).next('input').val());
if(val !== 0){
    $(this).next('input').val( val-1 );
} });
```

Comment: Thanks for jquery worked perfectly with the inputs WisdmLabs gave. TY

Answer (score 4):

You need add `.change();`

Better inside your `yourtheme/woocommerce/global/quantity-input.php`
In this way will work also in the cart page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.quantity').on('click', '.plus', function(e) {
        $input = $(this).prev('input.qty');
        var val = parseInt($input.val());
        $input.val( val+1 ).change();
    });

    $('.quantity').on('click', '.minus', 
        function(e) {
        $input = $(this).next('input.qty');
        var val = parseInt($input.val());
        if (val > 0) {
            $input.val( val-1 ).change();
        } 
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Display on the left the units (number with "+" and "-") to add for each product with add to cart button on the right. Put below code in **functions.php** file and add CSS code in **style.css** file.

```
//1. Show Buttons
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_quantity', 'display_quantity_plus' );
function display_quantity_plus() {
   echo '<button type="button" class="plus" >+</button>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_quantity', 'display_quantity_minus' );
function display_quantity_minus() {
   echo '<button type="button" class="minus" >-</button>';
}
//2. Trigger jQuery script
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_cart_quantity_plus_minus' );
function add_cart_quantity_plus_minus() {
   // Only run this on the single product page
   if ( ! is_product() ) return; ?>
      <script type="text/javascript">  
      jQuery(document).ready(function($){   
         $('form.cart').on( 'click', 'button.plus, button.minus', function() {
            // Get current quantity values
            var qty = $( this ).closest( 'form.cart' ).find( '.qty' );
            var val   = parseFloat(qty.val());
            var max = parseFloat(qty.attr( 'max' ));
            var min = parseFloat(qty.attr( 'min' ));
            var step = parseFloat(qty.attr( 'step' ));
            // Change the value if plus or minus
            if ( $( this ).is( '.plus' ) ) {
               if ( max && ( max <= val ) ) {
                  qty.val( max );
               } else {
                  qty.val( val + step );
               }
            } else {
               if ( min && ( min >= val ) ) {
                  qty.val( min );
               } else if ( val > 1 ) {
                  qty.val( val - step );
               }
            } 
         }); 
      });  
      </script>
   <?php
}
```

> CSS code

```
.woocommerce div.product .entry-summary .cart div.quantity{
    float: none;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
.woocommerce div.product form.cart .button {
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: This works great, but what about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67784840/persons-field-plus-minus-buttons

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add this to your Javascript:

```
$('.plus').on('click',function(e){

    var val = parseInt($(this).prev('input').val());

    $(this).prev('input').val( val+1 );


});

$('.minus').on('click',function(e){

    var val = parseInt($(this).next('input').val());

    $(this).next('input').val( val-1 );


});
```