# Woocommerce | Plus Minus remove negative numbers (min_value)

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce

I ask you for help please, I haven't come out of it for hours.

I set the quantity selector on the Woocommerce shop page,
which automatically puts the item in the cart and / or removes it.

I have a big problem, when I am on zero and I press - the numbers go negative, I would make sure that it cannot go below zero.

Thanks so much!!

Function.php

```
// Remove Add To cart Button
remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10);

// Add our Quanity Input
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'QTY');
function QTY()
{
    global $product;
    ?>
    <div class="shopAddToCart">
    <button  value="-" class="minus2"  >-</button>
    <input type="text"
    disabled="disabled"
    size="2"
    value="<?php echo (Check_if_product_in_cart($product->get_id())) ? Check_if_product_in_cart($product->get_id())['QTY'] : 0;
    ?>"
    id="count"
    data-product-id= "<?php echo $product->get_id() ?>"
    data-in-cart="<?php echo (Check_if_product_in_cart($product->get_id())) ? Check_if_product_in_cart($product->get_id())['in_cart'] : 0;
    ?>"
    data-in-cart-qty="<?php echo (Check_if_product_in_cart($product->get_id())) ? Check_if_product_in_cart($product->get_id())['QTY'] : 0;
    ?>"
    class="quantity qty qty-botton"
    max_value = "<?php echo ($product->get_max_purchase_quantity() == -1) ? 1000 : $product->get_max_purchase_quantity(); ?>"
    min_value = <?php echo $product->get_min_purchase_quantity(); ?>
    >

        <button type="button" value="+" class="plus2"  >+</button>

    </div>
                          <?php
}

//Check if Product in Cart Already
function Check_if_product_in_cart($product_ids)
 {

foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item):

    $items_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
    $QTY = $cart_item['quantity'];

    // for a unique product ID (integer or string value)
    if ($product_ids == $items_id):
        return ['in_cart' => true, 'QTY' => $QTY];

    endif;

endforeach;
}

//Add Event Handler To update QTY
add_action('wc_ajax_update_qty', 'update_qty');

function update_qty()
{
    ob_start();
    $product_id = absint($_POST['product_id']);
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];

    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item):

        if ($cart_item['product_id'] == $product_id) {
            WC()->cart->set_quantity($cart_item_key, $quantity, true);
        }

    endforeach;

    wp_send_json('done');
}
```

*.js jQuery on Footer

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
      "use strict";

      // Add Event Listner on the Plush button
      $('.plus2').click(function () {

        if (parseInt($(this).prev().val()) < parseInt($(this).prev().attr('max_value'))) {
          $(this).prev().val(+$(this).prev().val() + 1);
          var currentqty = parseInt($(this).prev().attr('data-in-cart-qty')) + 1;

          var id = $(this).prev().attr('data-product-id');

          var data = {
            product_id: id,
            quantity: 1
          };
          $(this).prev().attr('data-in-cart-qty', currentqty);
          $(this).parent().addClass('loading');
          $.post(wc_add_to_cart_params.wc_ajax_url.toString().replace('%%endpoint%%', 'add_to_cart'), data, function (response) {

            if (!response) {
              return;
            }

            if (response) {

              var url = woocommerce_params.wc_ajax_url;
              url = url.replace("%%endpoint%%", "get_refreshed_fragments");
              $.post(url, function (data, status) {
                $(".woocommerce.widget_shopping_cart").html(data.fragments["div.widget_shopping_cart_content"]);
                if (data.fragments) {
                  jQuery.each(data.fragments, function (key, value) {

                    jQuery(key).replaceWith(value);
                  });
                }
                jQuery("body").trigger("wc_fragments_refreshed");
              });
              $('.plus2').parent().removeClass('loading');

            }

          });


        }




      });



      $('.minus2').click(function () {

        $(this).next().val(+$(this).next().val() - 1);


        var currentqty = parseInt($(this).next().val());

        var id = $(this).next().attr('data-product-id');

        var data = {
          product_id: id,
          quantity: currentqty
        };
        $(this).parent().addClass('loading');
        $.post(wc_add_to_cart_params.wc_ajax_url.toString().replace('%%endpoint%%', 'update_qty'), data, function (response) {

          if (!response) {
            return;
          }

          if (response) {
            var url = woocommerce_params.wc_ajax_url;
            url = url.replace("%%endpoint%%", "get_refreshed_fragments");
            $.post(url, function (data, status) {
              $(".woocommerce.widget_shopping_cart").html(data.fragments["div.widget_shopping_cart_content"]);
              if (data.fragments) {
                jQuery.each(data.fragments, function (key, value) {

                  jQuery(key).replaceWith(value);
                });
              }
              jQuery("body").trigger("wc_fragments_refreshed");
            });
            $('.plus2').parent().removeClass('loading');
          }

        });




      });



    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a check before running the line:

```
$(this).next().val(+$(this).next().val() - 1);
```

that will become:

```
if ( $(this).next().val() > 0 ) {
    $(this).next().val(+$(this).next().val() - 1);
}
```

*Also note that you are using an identical id for each quantity input of each product. **The id attribute value should be unique on the page**.*

Here you can find some methods of adding plus and minus buttons in the quantity field of the add to cart form *(which you could take inspiration from)*:

- [Custom plus and minus quantity buttons in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52367826/custom-plus-and-minus-quantity-buttons-in-woocommerce-3)
- [WooCommerce plus and minus buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25942950/woocommerce-plus-and-minus-buttons)
- [WooCommerce: Add to Cart Plus & Minus Buttons](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-add-plus-minus-buttons-to-add-to-cart-quantity-input/)

Comment: Hello - I need help to work out how to isolate the IDs on my inputs: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67784840/persons-field-plus-minus-buttons

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Vincenzo Di Gaetano.

I solved it like this:

```
      $('.minus2').click(function () {
        
        var $minus2 = $(this);
        var oldValue = $minus2.parent().find("input").val();
        
        if (oldValue > 0) {
         $(this).next().val(+$(this).next().val() - 1);

        .....
```